# how do I pass an arraylist of hexadecimal values into char method in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, binary

In my approach below I have a text file of hex values that are passed into a string arraylist,  I have a working method that converts a character array into binary titled 'hexToBin'.

I am currently stuck and my question is how would I pass each hex value in the arraylist as a character string so I can use my conversion method to convert hexadecimal values into binary.

I am not allowed to use java's **automatic conversion methods** or **parse commands**

```
hexadecimal text file ~
33CDAEFFAD
032DAE01AD
196CDAEFC0
21A00D0000
100CDAEFFA
F3ABCDEFAB
29A0EDF301
3ABCDEFABC


import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    static void hexToBin(char hexdec[])
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (hexdec[i] != '\u0000')
        {
            switch (hexdec[i])
            {
                case '0':
                    System.out.print("0000");
                    break;
                case '1':
                    System.out.print("0001");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    System.out.print("0010");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    System.out.print("0011");
                    break;
                case '4':
                    System.out.print("0100");
                    break;
                case '5':
                    System.out.print("0101");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    System.out.print("0110");
                    break;
                case '7':
                    System.out.print("0111");
                    break;
                case '8':
                    System.out.print("1000");
                    break;
                case '9':
                    System.out.print("1001");
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    System.out.print("1010");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    System.out.print("1011");
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    System.out.print("1100");
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    System.out.print("1101");
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    System.out.print("1110");
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    System.out.print("1111");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("\nInvalid hexadecimal digit " + hexdec[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("RAMerrors8x4c"));
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            values.add(sc.nextLine());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
        {
            try {
                hexToBin(values.get(i).toCharArray());
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.print("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: I'm not asking you to outright write out code for me but can you elaborate further @Pali

Comment: hexToBin(sc.nextLine().toCharArray()) should work ... you read each line of your file as a string and you can get all characters of the String as an array of characters by calling its toCharArray method ...

Comment: @kai I am just helping to get the right output and not judging his code design :)

Comment: thank you guys for helping me instead of just downvoting and leaving, I guess this platform isn't welcome to people learning, nonetheless I have my code working now I just need to format it a little better.

Comment: remove the try/catch.

Comment: @kai when i remove it the compiler gives me an error in intelliJ:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at Main.hexToBin(Main.java:11)
 at Main.main(Main.java:81)

Comment: rather fix your while loop ( that is replace it with a for loop )

Comment: replace your "while (hexdec...)" loop with a "for (char c : hexdec)" loop (replacing all "hexdec[i]" with just "c") to get rid of the Exception. Java Strings are NOT null-terminated!!!

Comment: right to be even clearer: "while (hexdec[i] != '\u0000')" ->"for(char letter:hexdec){" plus replace "switch (hexdec[i])" -> "switch(letter)" and get rid of all the "i"s (in hexToBin)

Comment: Use `while(sc.hasNextLine())` instead of `while(sc.hasNext())` when are reading the file line by line.